# Slice/Page method return Reference in R2DBC is invalid?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc, r2dbc-mysql

In a nutShell , when i try to use slice/page as method reuturn value in r2dbc  , i  encounter the error  , below is two difference api reference and corrsponding error stack

1. `Flux<Slice<Object>>`

```
Flux<Slice<ChatMsg>> findBySessionId(Long sessionId , Pageable pageable);
```

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.ifx.account.entity.ChatMsg cannot be
 cast to class org.springframework.data.domain.Slice (com.ifx.account.entity.ChatMsg and
 org.springframework.data.domain.Slice are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

2. `Slice<Object>`

```
Slice<ChatMsg> findBySessionId(Long sessionId , Pageable pageable);
```

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method has to use a either multi-item reactive
 wrapper return type or a wrapped Page/Slice type; Offending method: public abstract 
org.springframework.data.domain.Slice 
com.ifx.account.repository.ChatMsgRepository.findBySessionId(java.lang.Long,org.springfram-
ework.data.domain.Pageable)
```

Is previous example in a incorrect way?  Alternatively , what should i do in order to troubleshoot?

Comment: Did you find a workaround or a solution for this.

Comment: ```Flux<ChatMsg> findBySessionId(Long sessionId , Pageable pageable);```  remove slice  or else  use ```Mono<Slice<object>>```